# Affect of EtOH on Anionic Surfactant

Tags: surfactants

I am not a chemist nor do I have a background in chemistry, so I know nothing beyond my observations.

Attempting to load SLS into a porous silica substrate by dissolving surfactant into 200 proof EtOH along with a lipid, held at 50c slow stirring on hot plate mag. Silica added once SLS and lipid are in solution. EtOH removed in Rotovap.

Question: does dissolving SLS in warm EtOH affect the surfactant's amphiphilic arrangement?

Comment: What do you mean by " surfactant's amphiphilic arrangement"? Do you mean CMC? Micelle size?